# jQuery UI Hover repeating

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this HTML:

```
<div>

    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="pop">Hello</div>
        Here is some content
        <br />
        It is several lines long.
        <br />
        This is the end of it.
    </div>

</div>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#wrap').hover(function() {
        $('#pop', $(this)).show('blind');

    }, function() {
        $('#pop', $(this)).hide('blind');
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Md5t5/)

Using jQuery UI.

If you move your mouse over the #wrap div #pop slides down and slides away again when you mouse out. But if you move your mouse into #wrap from above or move from #wrap into #pop before the animation finishes it loops forever (if you wait till the animation finishes, you can move between #wrap and #pop freely and nothing animates, which is what I want).

I've tried combinations of `mouseover`, `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`, filtering by `.not(':animated')`, calling `.stop()` before each call to `show`/`hide`, all of which give the same result which leads me to believe I'm missing something fundamental.

Could someone point me in the direction of what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hover callbacks don't work well with `show('blind')` and `hide('blind')`, but they should work OK with `slideUp()/slideDown()`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#wrap').hover(function() {
        console.log('over');
        $('#pop').slideDown();

    }, function() {
        console.log('out');
        $('#pop').slideUp();
    });
});​
```

---

Also, I'm not seeing infinite looping, but animations do get queued up.  If you move the mouse pointer quickly in and out of #wrap you'll generate a long string of animations.

#### EDIT:

I was able to get the infinite loop in FF.

Comment: Please change `$('#pop', this).slideDown();` to `$('#pop').slideDown();`. You don't need `this` context for ID selectors.

Comment: The infinite looping with `show` and `hide` only seems to happen on Firefox, but this works and it is beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for suggesting `slideDown`. I was trying to figure out why `mouseenter` is getting called while in animation. And yes it was happening in FF12 when you move the cursor inside `#pop` while animating. May be it is happening when it removes that `ui-wrapper` div at the end of animation which causes it to trigger `mouseenter` again.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my version with fix for `show('blind')`.

```
$(function() {
    var isAnimating = false;
    $('#wrap').hover(function() {
        if (!isAnimating) {
            isAnimating = true;
            $('#pop').show('blind', function () {
                setTimeout(function () { isAnimating = false; }, 100);
            });
        }
    }, function() {
        $('#pop').hide('blind');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Md5t5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

    $('#wrap').hover(function() {
        $('#pop', this).stop().show('blind');

    }, function() {
        $('#pop', this).stop().hide('blind');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Md5t5/1/​

Comment: Same problem. If you move your mouse onto the `Here is some content` line from above or from the left, so that when the #pop element appears it appears under your cursor, you should see it. It looks like the `.show()` is looping.

Comment: I couldn't get it to infinite loop by doing anything.

Comment: Seems to be a Firefox only issue.